# Outputting positions Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have written code that allows a user to input a sentence and then search for the positions of a certain word. How do I now adapt it so that when a sentence is input, the program then outputs the positions of each word **when it first occurs**?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim WordNumber As Integer = 0
        Dim StartofWord As Integer = 1
        Dim Text As String = ""
        Dim L As Integer = 0
        Dim Word As String

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence ")
        Dim LotsofText As String = UCase(Console.ReadLine)

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your word")
        Word = UCase(Console.ReadLine())

        'LotsofText= Console.ReadLine + " "
        If Mid(LotsofText, Len(LotsofText) - 1, 1) <> " " Then LotsofText = LotsofText + " "

        For L = 1 To LotsofText.Length
            If (Mid(LotsofText, L, 1)) = " " Then
                WordNumber = WordNumber + 1
                Text = (Mid(LotsofText, StartofWord, L - StartofWord))
                'Console.WriteLine(Text)
                StartofWord = L + 1

                If Text = Word Then
                    Console.WriteLine(WordNumber)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        If Not Text = Word Then
            Console.WriteLine("Error word not found")
        End If
        Console.Write("Press Enter to Exit")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: What is a word? Are you looking for substrings or words which are separated by delimiters(f.e. white-spaces or punctuation characters)?

Comment: Words separated by spaces @TimSchmelter

Comment: Are you looking for the word position or character position? i.e. "The quick brown fox", "brown" should output 2 (zero-based) or 10?

Comment: word position @Verdolino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no onboard method and it's not really simple. One approach is to iterate every character and to look if that is a space. If you have found one you need to find the beginning of the word because there could be consecutive spaces. Once you have that index you need to look for the next space because thats the end of the word. If this word equals the word you're searching you have the index.

Because it's quite difficult it's worth to write a method that can be reused, for example if you want to find all matching-indexes or the last. Therefore you can use iterators that meanwhile also exist in VB.NET. They allow to return things lazily, so only if you ask for them. If you ask for the first the method will break as soon as the first was returned:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function GetIndexesOfWord(input As String, wordToFind As String, Optional comparer As StringComparer = Nothing, Optional wordSeparator As Char = " "c) As IEnumerable(Of Int32)
    If comparer Is Nothing Then comparer = StringComparer.Ordinal
    For index As Int32 = 0 To input.Length - 1
        If index = 0 OrElse input(index) = wordSeparator Then
            Dim token = input.Substring(index)
            Dim trimmed = token.TrimStart(wordSeparator)
            index = index + (token.Length - trimmed.Length) ' start of word
            Dim endIndex = input.IndexOf(wordSeparator, index)
            If endIndex = -1 Then endIndex = input.Length
            Dim length = endIndex - index
            Dim word = input.Substring(index, length)
            If comparer.Equals(word, wordToFind) Then
                Yield index
            End If
            index = endIndex - 1 ' -1 because the for-loop will jump over the space otherwise
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Here's an example:

```
Dim sentence = "this is just sample text that contains a text sample"
Dim word = "sample"
Dim indexes = GetIndexesOfWord(sentence, word)
```

If you only want the first index:

```
Dim firstIndex As Int32 = indexes.First()
```

If you want all, you could fill a collection, for example:

```
Dim indexList As List(Of Int32) = indexes.ToList()
```

If you use the list you can check `lict.Count > 0` and you know if the word was in the sentence at all. If you use `First`, `Last` or other methods that return a single index, it's possible that you get an `InvalidOperationException` then. In that case `FirstOrdefault` doesn't help because the default value of `Int32` is 0 which is a valid index.  So you could use this approach to determine if there was a match and if there was one get the first index:

```
Dim firstIndex As Int32 = indexes.DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First()
```

Now you know that -1 means that the word was not in that sentence.

---

Since you are using Visual Studio 2010, then you can't use deferred execution which iterators and the `Yield`-statement in VB.NET. You either have to return the first found index which is efficient if you only need the first. Or you use this method that fills a list with all indexes:

```
Public Shared Function GetIndexesOfWord(input As String, wordToFind As String, Optional comparer As StringComparer = Nothing, Optional wordSeparator As Char = " "c) As IEnumerable(Of Int32)
    If comparer Is Nothing Then comparer = StringComparer.Ordinal

    Dim allIndexes = new List(Of Int32)
    For index As Int32 = 0 To input.Length - 1
        If index = 0 OrElse input(index) = wordSeparator Then
            Dim token = input.Substring(index)
            Dim trimmed = token.TrimStart(wordSeparator)
            index = index + (token.Length - trimmed.Length) ' start of word
            Dim endIndex = input.IndexOf(wordSeparator, index)
            If endIndex = -1 Then endIndex = input.Length
            Dim length = endIndex - index
            Dim word = input.Substring(index, length)
            If comparer.Equals(word, wordToFind) Then
               allIndexes.Add(index)
            End If
            index = endIndex - 1 ' -1 because the for-loop will jump over the space otherwise
        End If
    Next
    return allIndexes
End Function
```

Comment: Thankyou for the information however i would like the program to just output the positions straight away

Comment: @AonNovas: it does, if you want to output all use: `String.Join(",", indexes)`

Comment: When i try to use the code numerous errors appear :/

Comment: @AonNovas: what errors? What visual studio version do you use? Iterators work in VB.NET since Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Express

Comment: @AonNovas: that's the reason, at that time VB.NET didn't support `Yield`(iterators). I will write a version that works for you

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: i am having trouble with the Sub Main and the End Sub as when i insert the code above inbetween them it says that the End Sub must be matched with Sub... which i already have

Comment: @AonNovas: that's a method so you can't put it into another method. Just copy&paste it into a class and then call it via `classname.methodname`. If it's in the same class you can call it also via `methodname`, in this case `GetIndexesOfWord`